Running Python3 environment on Visual Studio Code but Python2 environment on its integrated terminal
VS code extension for robot framework works for me only on Python3, but my code can't be supported on Python3 - so I want to run it when opening integrated terminal from VS code on Python2 env.
Say that the Python3 env name is py3 and for Python2 is py2 - I wrote the following code on settings.json:
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "py2": {
            "path": "/bin/bash",
            "args": ["-c", "source /home/david/.virtualenvs/py2/bin/activate && exec bash"]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "py2"
}                      
               

And for VS code itself, I chose the interpreter ("Python: Select interpreter") to be for py3 environment.
So indeed VS code run on py3 as I want, but when I open integrated terminal on some path  - it's not being opened on any virtual environment when I expected it to be opened with py2.
Off course from here I can just execute workon py2 and it will work, but it's important for me that it will be set on that environment just as I open integrated terminal.
How can I fix that?

The python extension has long since stopped supporting python2.

You're trying to solve the wrong problem.
Stop using python2.
It went end-of-life years ago.
The web has numerous resources for aiding the transition of legacy code to python3.
It’s tedious, but not all that hard.
